# How to remove urls between texts in pandas dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, data-science

I am trying to solve a nlp problem, here in dataframe text column have lots of rows filled with `urls` like `http.somethingsomething`.some of the urls and other texts have no space between them for example- `':http:\\something'`,`';http:\\something'`,`',http:\\something'`.

so there sometime `,` before `url` text without any space and sometime something else but mostly `,` ,`.` ,`:`, `;`. and url either at the starting or at the end.

| id | text | target |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | we always try to bring the heavy metal rt `http:\\something11` | 1 |
| 4 | on plus side look at the sky last night it was ablaze `;http:\\somethingdifferent` | 1 |
| 6 | inec office in abia set ablaze `:http:\\itsjustaurl` | 1 |
| 3 | `.http:\\something11` we always try to bring the heavy metal rt | 1 |

so i want to know how can i remove these links. I am using `python` language for task.

Comment: Are the URLs always the final part of the text?  Or, could they also occur in the middle of the text, and, if so, can you include some examples of this?

Comment: they are the final part most of the time.

Comment: "most of the time" <-- unfortunately, this is not enough information to give you a complete answer.  Please include the requested sample data.

Comment: so there is only two cases where url either at the starting or at the end.

Comment: For the cases where the URL is _not_ the last thing in the text, can we always assume that there would be at least one whitespace character following that URL?

Comment: yes there for the cases where the URL is not the last thing, there always one  or many  whitespace character following that URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach would be to just remove any URL starting with `http` or `https`:

```py
df["text"] = df["text"].str.replace(r'\s*https?://\S+(\s+|$)', ' ').str.strip()
```

There is some subtle logic in the above line of code which merits some explanation.  We capture a URL, with optional whitespace on the left and mandatory whitespace on the right (except for when the URL continues to the end).  Then, we replace that with a single space, and use `strip()` in case this operation would leave dangling whitespace at the start/end.

Comment: there is a problem in this approach, some of the urls and other texts have not space between them, therefore some of the urls still left.

Comment: Then you're going to need to update your question with sample data.  It could be tricky to figure out what the right ending of a URL would be (left side is pretty obvious, just start matching `https?`).

Comment: just updated question. i think this time question is more clearer.

Comment: @Niro I have updated based on your (now complete) sample data.